# How to append duplicate rows as columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to append the duplicated rows in one column. Duplication is based on some columns that need to be an exact match for a row to declare as a match.
the problem is we can't say how many repeated rows will be there so the solution needs to be generic.

I have tried some other solution but they are based on some user_id or key column. In my case, all columns except one have to be compared exactly. and appended columns should have the same column name.

I used following code to find duplicated rows:

```
col = ['TITLE', 'ISSN', 'e-ISSN', 'ISBN', 'e-ISBN']
duplicated_data = data[data.duplicated(col, keep=False)]
```

Now I don't know what to do next

Here is a sample input output

input data:

```
------------------------------
DealName | Target | Category |
-----------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | ABC    | A        |
------------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | ABC    | B        |
------------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | None   | C        |
```

output data:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DealName | Target | Category |DealName | Target | Category 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC-XYZ  | ABC    | A        |ABC-XYZ  | ABC    | B
```

Suppose I have set the condition that the first two columns need to be matched in order to select the row since 3rd row does not have the same value in the second column we ignored it.

Comment: Please, do not post pictures of data. There are a number of formatting options to make it easy for you to post the actual text.

Comment: @Jacobr365 I am sorry I will edit it. Any specific reason for not posting the picture?

Comment: You are still just posting the image. Comma separated data we can copy and past would be best. We don't like pictures because if we are trying to recreate your issue and you have only provided images, then we need to look at the images and transcribe all of your data. If you post the data as text, we can just copy and paste it. It just makes it easier to help you, and increases the chances someone will take the time to help.

Comment: It's impossible to copy/paste it and play with the data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have edited the post

Comment: I struggle to understand how `input` becomes `output`. None of the values appear in input

Comment: @Gio I have updated the values